# Syntax highlight in bugzilla

Tags: ubuntu, bugzilla

I have Bugzilla installed on Ubuntu Server. Is that possible to add syntax highlight to Bugzilla comments (for C++ code)? Now code pasted in comments looks not well formatted and it makes harder to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately that's not yet implemented, though people have asked for it:

[Last Comment Bug 358987 - Show attachments with colored syntax highlighting in certain views](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=358987)

An alternative might be to put a code highlighting tool into your browser. There are at least tow Firefox add-ons which do that:

CodeViewer: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/6855

CodeSnippet: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/9113

They let you select code in a web page and display it with highlighting.

Comment: Firefox plugin is not an option. May be there are available onofficial syntax highlight patches?